# Google search returns results in wrong language on all workstations in a LAN

Tags: google-chrome, lan, active-directory, google-search, geolocation

I'm system admin at network consisting of ~250 Win10 workstations, with Active Directory. Network is NATed behind a firewall (Fortigate FG-201F). Public IP address of our firewall is in the RIPE DB, correctly indicating country (Bosnia-Herzegovina). All geolocation online services correctly shows my country. However, Google maps thinks we are in Bulgaria, which is some 500km to the east. All advertisments in browsers on all workstations in the network are for Bulgarian market, in Bulgarian language. Google search returns results in Bulgarian language. Youtube same. We asked Google several times to change our location, but nothing happened. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: You state, "However, Google maps thinks we are in Bulgaria, which is some 500km to the east." Likely, this is either due to your ISP being there, or using a VPN with server there.

Answer (score 0):

If users are signed into a google account in the browser, then it should be more accurate.

- Language is usually based on your browser preferences. For example Chrome, you can set this here: [chrome://settings/?search=languages](https://chrome://settings/?search=languages)

  - Chrome and Edge browsers support setting language preferences via [group policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202)
- You can statically assign a language to google accounts here: https://myaccount.google.com/language
- You can improve google search results by using the correct tld, like https://www.google.hr/ for bosnia.

Other than that, you will probably have to wait for google to update their Geo-IP database